# insert into a table in database using the result of insertion to another table in one php code

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I have two table: word(id,word,meaning) and userword(id,wordid,userid)
in both of them id is auto increment.
In a form I get word and the meaning from user and then I want to insert this word into these to table. Insertion to words works well but for insertion to userword I have to get wordid from words and then insert into userword but it doesn't work
here is my form:

```
 <form action="InsertWord.php" method="post">
                                <input name="word" id="word" type="text" maxlength="255" />
                                <label for="user">:word</label></br></br>
                                <input name="meaning" id="mean" type="text" maxlength="255" />
                                <label for="pass">:meaning</label></br></br>
                                <input type="submit" value="insert" /></br></br>
 </form>
```

and InsertWord.php:

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
  or die(mysql_error());   
  if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
   } 
  mysql_select_db("project", $con)
  or die(mysql_error()); 
  if(isset($_POST["word"]) && isset($_POST["meaning"])) 
    { 
    $word = $_POST["word"];
    $meaning = $_POST['meaning'];
    $user= $_SESSION['userid'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO words (word,meaning) values ('".$word."','".$meaning."')") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $qwordid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM words WHERE word='$word'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $fwordid = mysql_fetch_array($qwordid); 
    $wordid= $fwordid['id'];    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO userword (user_id,word_id) values ('".$user."','".$wordid."')") or die(mysql_error()); 

   //HEADER('LOCATION: InsertIntoUserword.php');
} 
 else 
    die('wrong!'); 

  ?>
```

because I insert into words and then database not refreshed it doesn't work for userword
what can I do?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, here is [good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_insert_id()` but I recomend change to mysqli or PDO extension, because mysql extension will be deprecated and remove in a future, you can see this in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: I have wordid and I don't have any problem in this case
but I want to use this wordid in another query but because database not refreshed it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

The function `mysql_insert_id()` returns the id of the last inserted row:

```
$wordid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: My problem isn't about wordid
I need to refresh database in the middle of code